# sqlite3 C API containing two databases,pointers of both databases are the same

Tags: c, database, sqlite

I'm using the sqlite3 C API and have two databases in my project. they are called as EPG and the REC database respectively.I open them using a functions called as

```
     re_db_epg_init();
     re_db_rec_init();
```

the codes of both of them are as follows:

re_db_epg_init()

```
  void re_epg_db_init(void)
{
int status = sqlite3_initialize();

s_dbepg_path=re_dbepg_get_path(); //get the path of the database

//openrecDB

   status=sqlite3_open_v2(s_dbepg_path,&s_re_dbepg,SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY,NULL);
//check status
  if(status!=SQLITE_OK){
  printf("\n\nerror occured in opening epg database \n");
   exit(0);
             }

 status=sqlite3_extended_result_codes(s_re_dbepg,1);
  printf("\n\nstatus for opening the epg db is = %d \n",status);

   }
```

and re_db_rec_init()

```
    void re_rec_db_init(void)
  {
  int status;     
  s_dbrec_path=re_dbrec_get_path();

   status=sqlite3_open_v2(s_dbrec_path,&s_re_dbrec,SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE|SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE,NULL);
    //check status
      if(status!=SQLITE_OK){
   printf("\n\nerror occured in opening rec database \n");
exit(0);   
}


status=sqlite3_extended_result_codes(s_re_dbrec,1);
printf("\n\nstatus for opening the rec db is = %d \n",status);
}
```

Therefore when I call the functions I should have two pointers s_re_dbepg,s_re_dbrec which act as handles for the two databases. But when I print them out,they give the same value(some random hex value). therefore I am able to perform all operations on the EPG database whereas on the second one all my operations fail.I really don't know why the pointers are giving the same value. Is there any way to rectify this such that both my DB's operate smoothly?

Comment: Your code appears to be correct. The error must be somewhere else. What are the definitons of `s_re_dbepg` and `s_re_dbrec`?

Comment: they are sqlite3 * type ie sqlite3 *s_re_dbepg, *s_re_dbrec

Comment: What if you print the pointer value right inside the `*_init` functions, eg: `printf("s_re_dbepg points to %p\n", (void*)s_re_dbepg);`? Do they still give the same value?

Comment: tried what you told me.. the print values are the same.. also i would like to add here that i'm comfortably able to read data from the epg database and manipulate it whereas im not able to write the same into the rec database..

Comment: I [wrote a program(ish) that works for me](http://pastebin.com/3XhtTxde). It copies, row by row, the data in the `x` table of a database to the `x` table of another database.

Comment: Thanks for the code.. I'll try to use it in my program and let you know if it worked:) cheers